# Multiple exceptions thrown parsing date string

Tags: java, tomcat, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse a string into a date in the constructor of an object, which we will call `Example`. Here is the code

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

private long time;

public Example(String date) {
    try {
        this.time = sdf.parse(date).getTime();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception while parsing date " + date, e);
    }
}
```

Now, I am creating these objects in a Tomcat instance (whether that makes any difference or not).

I get the following types of exceptions

```
Fri Jul 06 15:13:48 EDT 2012 WARNING: Exception while parsing date 2012-07-06 18:57:31
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:431)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
    at java.text.DigitList.getLong(DigitList.java:177)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1297)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1589)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1311)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
    at ...
Fri Jul 06 15:13:48 EDT 2012 WARNING: Exception while parsing date 2012-07-06 19:00:07
java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1082)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at java.text.DigitList.getDouble(DigitList.java:151)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1302)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1934)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1311)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
    at ...
Fri Jul 06 15:13:48 EDT 2012 WARNING: Exception while parsing date 2012-07-06 19:13:21
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.text.DigitList.fitsIntoLong(DigitList.java:212)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1295)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1934)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1311)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
    at ...
Fri Jul 06 15:48:06 EDT 2012 WARNING: Exception while parsing last check string 2012-07-06 19:08:08
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".200172E4.200172"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at java.text.DigitList.getDouble(DigitList.java:151)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1302)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1589)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1311)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
    at ...
```

So it fails for the dates

```
2012-07-06 18:57:31
2012-07-06 19:00:07
2012-07-06 19:13:21
2012-07-06 19:08:08
```

However, if I make a unit test I get the following values for `time` from these strings

```
1341615451000
1341615607000
1341616401000
1341616088000
```

So the `SimpleDateFormat` object does work... but not on the server? I have noticed that this issue occurs near the startup of the server, and then not later on, if that helps at all. Not really sure what to do next.

Using Tomcat 7.0 and Java 1.6 update 32.

Comment: i suspect you are passing empty strings into your Example constructor when you deploy.

Comment: @hvgotcodes I don't see how that's possible since I am logging the string that is passed into the constructor as you can see in the logs

Comment: Maybe it's a concurrency issue ? SimpleDateFormat seems not to be thread safe 
http://blog.palantir.com/2007/07/simpledateformat-is-not-thread-safe/

Comment: Is SimpleDateFormat sensitive to locale?

Comment: @cporte wow, that was it! I synchronized access to the `sdf` object and it seems to be working fine. Leave an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Do not synchronize, but create a new SimpleDateFormat locally every time. That prevents an artificial bottleneck, paid by a bit of object overhead.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe, as explained https://www.palantir.com/2007/07/simpledateformat-is-not-thread-safe/ 
Sometimes, really strange or non-logical behaviors when using "static" objects comes from concurrency issues

To resolve such a case, use a new instance each time (It is better than synchronizing, as synchronization can raise a bottleneck issue)

Comment: I was getting the exact same error from an Apache Spark job I would submit to the cluster - had the hardest time figuring out what the problem was because the exact same job would run locally just fine on the exact same data.  It turns out it was this same issue!  I was using the same SimpleDateFormat in all the threads.

Comment: Link is broken, but why you're citing third parties instead of the Javadoc is a mystery.

Answer (score 5):

SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe: see the Javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

As of Java 8+, it might be better to prefer a `java.time` based solution.

The classes in `java.time` are **thread safe**.

You can achieve the equivalent date extraction like that:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

...

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(str, dockerDateFormatter);
```

and then query the fields you need from `date`.

More details in the JavaDoc for [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

Another [TLDR resource](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html) with two ready-to-use examples.

Comment: Or skip the formatter and just replace the SPACE with a "T" for a standard ISO 8601 format used by default in java.time: `LocalDateTime.parse( "2012-07-06 18:57:31".replace( " " , "T" ) )`

Comment: I really don't understand how this is possible. this fixed my issue. I don't understand how by using a formatter to parse for a date and the output to be from another string in another thread . like wtf? :) what did they do? :)))